# AJW Feedparser feed stopped working

Tags: plugin, xml, rss

I have a site that has been using AJW Feedparser to embed an xml feed for months without problems, but has recently stopped working.

If I open the cache file, the feed info is there, but it is no longer being parsed in my EE template.

I tried setting the item path parameter to channel/item but it didn't make a difference. Is there some other parameter I'm missing?

My template code:

```
{exp:ajw_feedparser 
url="feed"
cache_refresh="60"
limit="8"
parse="inward"
debug="true"
}
    <tr>
        <td class="four">
            <p class="meta">{event_start} {if event_end != event_start} - {event_end}{/if}</p>
        </td>
        <td class="eight">
    <h3 class="title zeta"><a href="{link}" title="More Information">{title}</a></h3>
        </td>
    </tr>
{/exp:ajw_feedparser}
```

My feed code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<channel>
    <atom:link href="feed url" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <title>Events</title>
    <ttl>500</ttl>
    <item>
        <title>Event Title</title>
        <event_start>06/06/15</event_start>
        <event_end>06/06/15</event_end>
        <description>Event Description</description>
        <link>Event URL</link>
    </item>
    ...
```

EDIT: It appears that the plugin is choking on some ascii characters in the feed. I don't have access to change the feed's encoding. Is there a way to get the plugin to handle the ascii characters?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem too. The 'proper' solution is to ensure that the feed's fields are wrapped with CDATA markers, but that might not be possible in all circumstances.